# To disable the integrated camera on laptop having ubuntu os

Tags: ubuntu, camera

To disable the integrated camera on laptop having Ubuntu/Centos  os

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot your system and press F12,F8 based on the laptop settings enter the bios setup option

2.Select BiosSetup option from the list and navigate to System Configuration

3.Once Selected System COnfiguration option select Video option

4. In the video option uncheck the "Enable Camera" options and reboot the sys

This the simplest way to disable the integrated webcam on laptop having ubuntu /centos OS

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your integrated camera using this command:

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/bConfigurationValue
```

---

Here,
It's 1-6 for me. You can find out your variant using:

```
lsusb -t
```

It would give output somewhat like:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

It says port 6 has video driver.
Now type this command:

```
cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/; ls
```

It would give output somewhat like:

```
1-0:1.0  1-14  1-14:1.0  1-14:1.1  1-6  1-6:1.0  1-6:1.1  1-9  1-9:1.0  2-0:1.0  usb1  usb2
```

You can find variant 1-6 by comapring port from above command here. Here, 1-6.
You can verify this by comparing vendor and product ids. Type this command but use your variant in place of 1-6.

```
cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6 && cat id{Vendor,Product}
```

NOTE: USE YOUR VARIANT IN PLACE OF 1-6.
It would give vendor and product ids.

```
04ca
7070
```

Now type this command:

```
lsusb
```

It will give list of devices connected through usb.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:c100 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It has same vendor:products ids as 1-6 has. i.e. 04ca:7070

Put your variant of 1-6 in the command to disable integrated camera:

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/bConfigurationValue
```

If you recieve "bash: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/bConfigurationValue: Permission denied" then you can change permissions using following command.

Note: Use your variant of 1-6.

```
sudo chmod 777 /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6
```

You can enable camera using this command:

```
sudo echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/bConfigurationValue
```